# Display All Data with PHP AJAX JSON using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

filePHP.php

```
$query = $kon->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_kategori");
$query->execute();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $json = array('id' => $row['id_kategori'], 'nama' => $row['nama_kategori']);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

and index.php

```
$.post('filePHP.php', function(data){
   console.log(data);
},'json');
```

but this not working, what would solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide information on what is not working.  Error message, returned data, expected data.  There can never be too much information

Comment: ohh i'm sorry @elzaer

Comment: in you ajax you are using "proses.php" while code is in "filePHP.php".

Comment: @developerCK : sorry for the file name,, but this code copy/paste from my project, mr. ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in **PHP**

```
$query = $kon->prepare("SELECT id_kategori,nama_kategori FROM t_kategori");
$query->execute();
$json=array();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $arr=array('id'=>$row['id_kategori'],'nama'=>$row['nama_kategori']);
    array_push($json,$arr);
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Read **[array-push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)**

Comment: best coding practice says you should use column name instead of asterisk(*).
Use array_push() in loop

Comment: @Ryo check the `file name` you `passed` in `$.post` as Both are looking different in your `question` and in `$.post`

Comment: @rohan : ohh sorry,,, but this source copy/paste from my project .. hehehe

Answer (score 1):

try something like this , your code will echo json in wrong format whereas below code will give you json array.

```
$query = $kon->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_kategori");
$query->execute();
$json_arr =array();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $temp_arr = array();
    $temp_arr['id'] => $row['id_kategori'];
    $temp_arr['nama'] => $row['nama_kategori'];
    array_push($json_arr,$temp_arr);
}

echo json_encode($json_arr);
```